# Losing documents in my collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm looking for suggestions on how to debug this one.

When one of my documents gets too large in a collection, the entire document is removed from the collection. I'm using heroku with mongoid 2.2.6 and rails 3.0.20 with MongoHQ. I'm unable to reproduce the problem locally.

We started writing this code two years ago and it's been slowly maintained by some of my students. The site is similar to a basic blogging site where a "post" will have "comments." The initial design had the post versioned and each post contains all of the comments. Because of versioning, the size of the document can grow very quickly. We tried to limit the size of the versions with max_versions 5, but we can still reproduce the problem with extremely large comments. It may be the case that the site is fully useable, but since we loose the entire document (and not just the comment), I'd like to find a solution. Had I noticed that the comments were being versioned within the document, I'd have change the design to store comments outside of the post.

Comment: A single MongoDB doc cannot exceed 16 MB so you could check for docs nearing that size. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size

Comment: You should also be sure you're using safe writes when creating and saving documents so you're alerted to any errors that occur.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment said, it is likely that your document simply grows too large. Since a while, all the MongoDB drivers default to Acknowledged Writes, which in most cases will give you an exception if a document can't be stored or updated. Please check whether you use a recent driver version and/or have Acknowledged Writes turned on (sometimes also called "safe").

I still think your best bet is to change your schema. If you have an unbound amount of comments then you will run into this problem, even without versioning at some point. Alternatively, you can store older comments and/or posts in a separate collection.

Answer (score 0):

A few pieces of info that may help:

- The server will not delete the document if it grows past the 16MB limit; instead it will raise an error (e.g. Invalid size).
- To the best of my knowledge, there's nothing in Mongoid nor the MongoDB Ruby driver that would delete the document if an update operation fails.
- If the application removes a document and then inserts a new document for every update, I would suggest modifying the application to leverage updates and simply ensure any errors are handled appropriately.